# Change configuration parameters from command-line or programatically

Tags: postgresql, fabric

How can I change settings in `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` either from the command-line or programatically (especially from `fabric` or `fabtools`)?

I already found `set_config`, but that does not seem to work for parameters which require a server restart. The parameters to change are `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` and a new line in `pg_hba.conf`, so connections from our sub-network will be accepted.

This is needed to write deployment scripts using `fabric`. It is not an option to copy template-files which then override the existing `*.conf` files, because the database server might be shared with other applications which bring their own configuration parameters. Thus, the existing configuration must be *altered*, not replaced.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html

Comment: That solved the `listen_addresses` part, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the currently working solution, incorporating the hint from a_horse_with_no_name. I paste a snippet from our `fabfile.py` (it uses `require` from `fabtools`, and it runs against `Ubuntu`):

```
db_name = env.variables['DB_NAME']
db_user = env.variables['DB_USER']
db_pass = env.variables['DB_PASSWORD']

# Require a PostgreSQL server.
require.postgres.server(version="9.4")
require.postgres.user(db_user, db_pass)
require.postgres.database(db_name, db_user)

# Listen on all addresses - use firewall to block inadequate access.
sudo(''' psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses='*';" ''', user='postgres')

# Download the remote pg_hba.conf to a temp file
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
with open(tmp.name, "w") as f:
    get("/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf", f, use_sudo=True)

# Define the necessary line in pg_hba.conf.
hba_line = "host    all     all     {DB_ACCEPT_IP}/0   md5".format(**env.variables)

# Search the hba_line in the existing pg_hba.conf
with open(tmp.name, "ra") as f:
    for line in f:
        if hba_line in line:
           found = True
           break
    else:
        found = False

# If it does not exist, append it and upload the modified pg_hba.conf to the remote machine.
if not found:
    with open(tmp.name, "a") as f:
        f.write(hba_line)
    put(f.name, "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf", use_sudo=True)

# Restart the postgresql service, so the changes take effect.
sudo("service postgresql restart")
```

The aspect I don't like with this solution is that if I change `DB_ACCEPT_IP`, this will just append a new line and not remove the old one. I am sure a cleaner solution is possible.